# Script for initial build of Angular 2 project?

Tags: node.js, npm

How can I write a script for npm that installs the node_modules in an angular 2 project and compiles the ts files. This doesn't work:

```
"scripts": {
"firstBuild": "npm install && tsc", 
....
```

I get the error:

```
> npm firstBuild

Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
```

PS:

I can run `"start" : "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\"` just like `npm start` , why can't I do `npm firstBuild` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just forgot to use `run`.

Try `npm run firstBuild`.

Comment: But I can run `"start" : "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ` just like `npm start`, why can't I do npm firstBuild ?